# React.js give cannot read props of undefined, when have are no props in project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios

I'm trying to get a image to show up from an API but it gives me this error : TypeError: Cannot set property 'props' of undefined. But I didn't use props in my code. I've been trying to trouble shoot this for almost 2 hours.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'


class App extends Component(){

  state = {
    photo : ''
  }

  handleonClick = () => {

    axios.get('https://api.nasa.gov/mars-photos/api/v1/rovers/curiosity/photos?sol=1000&api_key=DEMO_KEY').then( url => {

      console.log(url.data.photos[0].img_src)
      this.setState({

        photo : url.data.photos[0].img_src

      });
    })
  }

  componentDidMount(){

    axios.get('https://api.nasa.gov/mars-photos/api/v1/rovers/curiosity/photos?sol=1000&api_key=DEMO_KEY')
    .then( url => {

      console.log(url.data.photos[0].img_src)
      this.setState({

        photo : url.data.photos[0].img_src

      });
    })

  }

  render(){


   

    return(

      <div>
        <h1>Photos of Mars</h1>
        <img src={this.state.photo}/>
        <button className='new-image-btn' onClick={this.handleonClick}>New image</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: The error is not from this code.  Show the code where you call for the `<App/>` component.

Comment: extending a function? `Component()`

Answer (score 2):

It's a typo `Component()`. Change it to `Component` and it will work.

`class App extends Component`

[CodeSandbox Link for your code](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-component-typo-cnv72)

Answer (score 0):

maybe if you removed the () after the "class App extends Component" and try it would work .
you can check the react doc for creation of class based component
[react Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html)!